# Create SO style related questions

Tags: php, mysql

Stack Overflow offers related questions (on the right side of this question).  I have been trying to recreate this using this PHP code where `$question_title` is the user's title of the question:

```
<?php

$where='';

$question_title = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$question_title); 
$total_keywords = count($question_title);

foreach($question_title as $key=>$question_title) {
    $where .= "`questiontitle` LIKE '%$question_title%'";
    if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)) {
        $where .= " AND ";
    }
}

$results="SELECT `questiontitle` FROM questions WHERE $where";

$results_num = ($results=mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results) : 0;
echo $results;

if ($results_num == 0) {                
    return false;       
} else {
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo $row['questiontitle'];
    }
}

?>
```

The problem is that this code only returns the current question.  I guess the LIKE condition in my query is too specific.  How would I change this to allow questions with just a few common words to show up?

Comment: `foreach($question_title as $key=>$question_title)` Please don't shadow variable names like that, it makes baby StackOverflow cry.

Comment: You're using the same variable name for the individual values in your loop, and the thing you're iterating over. Don't do that.

Comment: @Amber ok, but will this fix the problem?

Comment: No, hence why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Do you have matching questions in your database. And to solve your problem try using `FULLTEXT` search. You need to set `FULLTEXT` index on search column and then use

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MATCH (column_name) AGAINST ('keyword') syntax.
```

Check this link for more details [MySQL FULLTEXT search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Comment: thanks but how can i set my column to FULLTEXT?  is there an SQL statement

Comment: Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.  

A FULLTEXT index definition can be given in the CREATE TABLE statement when a table is created, or added later using ALTER TABLE or CREATE INDEX. check this link - [Full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)